# Accordion with prototype 1.7

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am migrating an application from prototype 1.4 to prototype 1.7.
In this application moo.fx is used for the accordian.
And a lot of code has been written for the effects like text autogrow.
I couldnt find an updated version for moo.fx based on prototype other than 1.4 version.
Do I need to choose some other alternative?
And what could that alternative be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [script.aculo.us](http://script.aculo.us/) which goes hand in hand with prototype